# Can the PayPal Sandbox really charge credit cards

Tags: paypal

I have created a registration system that uses PayPal for the payment processing.

We had people that registered for an event when the system was in sandbox mode.  They are claiming that their credit cards were charged.

Is this even possible?

Thanks for any incite.

Comment: Well that's not quite true - today 3 transactions that went through my sandbox account were charged their genuine cards. Trying to resolve it with PayPal at the moment.

Comment: saw that the card got charged in sandbox mode as well